# show all the matched string in pyspark dataframe

Tags: pyspark

I wanted to show all the filtered results of similar matched string.

codes:

```
# Since most of the stackoverflow questionaire-s and also answerer-s are all super SMART and leave out all the necessary import libraries and required codes before using pyspark so that the readers can crack their minds in researching more instead of getting direct answer, I share the codes from beginning as below in order for future reviewers. 

# Import libraries
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkContext

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Initiate the session
spark = SparkSession\
            .builder\
            .appName('Operations')\
            .getOrCreate()

# sc = SparkContext()
sc =SparkContext.getOrCreate()

# Create dataframe 1
sdataframe_temp = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1,2,'3'),
    (2,2,'yes')],
    ['a', 'b', 'c']
)

# Create Dataframe 2
sdataframe_temp2 = spark.createDataFrame([
    (4,6,'yes'),
    (5,7,'yes')],
    ['a', 'b', 'c']
)

# Combine dataframe
sdataframe_union_1_2 = sdataframe_temp.union(sdataframe_temp2)

# Filter out the columns based on respective rules
sdataframe_temp\
    .filter(sdataframe_union_1_2['c'] == 'yes')\
    .select(['a', 'b'])\ # I wish to stick with dataframe method if possible.
    .show()
```

Output:

```
+---+---+
|  a|  b|
+---+---+
|  2|  2|
+---+---+
```

Expected output:

```
+---+---+
|  a|  b|
+---+---+
|  2|  2|
+---+---+
|  4|  6|
+---+---+
|  5|  7|
+---+---+
```

Can anyone please give some suggestions or improvement?

Comment: Change `sdataframe_temp` to `sdataframe_union_1_2` in your last line ?

Comment: Can I know what do you mean? My last line is combining both sdataframe_temp with sdataframe_temp2

Comment: I mean the filter line. You are filtering on the first data frame only. So you only get data from first data frame?

Comment: Ah, I see. now i get it. Omg, my mistakes. Thank you so much for telling me.

Comment: Can you tell me also of how can I add new values to spark dataframe? I cant find the right info. My code is like this. I wish to add new column named 'e' to sdataframe_union_1_2 = sdataframe_union_1_2.withColumn('e', [1,2,3,4])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way using [`unionByName`](http://sdataframe_temp1.unionByName(sdataframe_temp2).where(%22c%20==%20'yes'%22).drop('c').show()):

```
df = (sdataframe_temp1
      .unionByName(sdataframe_temp2)
      .where("c == 'yes'")
      .drop('c'))

df.show()

+---+---+
|  a|  b|
+---+---+
|  2|  2|
|  4|  6|
|  5|  7|
+---+---+
```

Comment: Thanks! This is great! I wanted to learn new pyspark way so this is the way that I want. thank you

Comment: Sir do you think you could assist me on another question> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59807555/show-all-pyspark-columns-after-group-and-agg

Answer (score 0):

you should change last line of code. for `col` function you should import from `pyspark.sql.functions`

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

sdataframe_union_1_2\
.filter(col('c') == 'yes')\
.select(['a', 'b'])\ # I wish to stick with dataframe method if possible.
.show()
```

or

```
sdataframe_union_1_2\
.filter(sdataframe_union_1_2['c'] == 'yes')\
.select(['a', 'b'])\ # I wish to stick with dataframe method if possible.
.show()
```

you have to select data from `sdataframe_union_1_2` and you are selecting from `sdataframe_temp` that's why you are getting one record.