# Show all pyspark columns after group and agg

Tags: pyspark

I wish to groupby a column and then find the max of another column. Lastly, show all the columns based on this condition. However, when I used my codes, it only show 2 columns and not all of it.

```
# Normal way of creating dataframe in pyspark
sdataframe_temp = spark.createDataFrame([
    (2,2,'0-2'),
    (2,23,'22-24')],
    ['a', 'b', 'c']
)

sdataframe_temp2 = spark.createDataFrame([
    (4,6,'4-6'),
    (5,7,'6-8')],
    ['a', 'b', 'c']
)
# Concat two different pyspark dataframe
sdataframe_union_1_2 = sdataframe_temp.union(sdataframe_temp2)

sdataframe_union_1_2_g = sdataframe_union_1_2.groupby('a').agg({'b':'max'})

sdataframe_union_1_2_g.show()
```

output:

```
+---+------+
|  a|max(b)|
+---+------+
|  5|     7|
|  2|    23|
|  4|     6|
+---+------+
```

Expected output:

```
+---+------+-----+
|  a|max(b)| c   |
+---+------+-----+
|  5|     7|6-8  |
|  2|    23|22-24|
|  4|     6|4-6  |
+---+------+---+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`Window function`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=window#pyspark.sql.Window) to make it work:

> **Method 1: Using Window function**

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w = Window().partitionBy("a").orderBy(F.desc("b"))

(sdataframe_union_1_2
.withColumn('max_val', F.row_number().over(w) == 1)
.where("max_val == True")
.drop("max_val")
.show())

+---+---+-----+
|  a|  b|    c|
+---+---+-----+
|  5|  7|  6-8|
|  2| 23|22-24|
|  4|  6|  4-6|
+---+---+-----+
```

**Explanation**

1. `Window` functions are useful when we want to attach a new column to the existing set of columns.
2. In this case, I tell `Window` function to groupby `partitionBy('a')` column and sort the column `b` in descending order `F.desc(b)`. This make the first value in `b` in each group its max value.
3. Then we use `F.row_number()` to filter the max values where row number equals 1.
4. Finally, we drop the new column since it is not being used after filtering the data frame.

> **Method 2: Using groupby + inner join**

```
f = sdataframe_union_1_2.groupby('a').agg(F.max('b').alias('b'))

sdataframe_union_1_2.join(f, on=['a','b'], how='inner').show()

+---+---+-----+
|  a|  b|    c|
+---+---+-----+
|  2| 23|22-24|
|  5|  7|  6-8|
|  4|  6|  4-6|
+---+---+-----+
```

Comment: Can you explain a little about the method you used? I see that my groupby and agg functions are not used and still get the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks! But will it be possible to use my method but at the same time using the window method too> I wish to learn more different ways of doing it. That only if it is possible to do it. thank you again

Comment: that's good, you can do that with more steps. after you have grouped df, you need to inner join it with `sdataframe_union_1_2` to get the result.

Comment: I am so sorry but could you include it in your above answer?

Comment: done, please check. Do accept the answer it it helps:)

Comment: Do you know why, it takes forever to use .show() in larger dataset? Isnt there a way to display the result like in pandas which we can display at the last process result? Can you share some knowledge with me please sir.